# Asp.Net VB web forms GridView how to reorganize the data from an sql datasource?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I'm developing a clock In and Clock Out report, The purpose of this report is to show the employee Clock in/out times in a easily readable format and to calculate and output the total hours worked.

The problem I'm having is with the Activity_DtTm column since it stores all clock in/out dates. The Activity_CD column identifies clock in with 1 and clock out with 2. The problem occurs when i separate the Activity_DtTm column into two other columns as Clock_In and Clock_Out. Both values will output on different row indexes due to null/empty spaces.

The database version is SQL Server 2000

Gridview output:

[image]

Required gridview output:

[image]

Query used for the output:

```
Try
dt = SQL.ExecQuery("Select E.Str_ID, e.Emp_ID, (e.Last_Nm + ' ' + E.Frst_Nm) As Name, T.Bus_DT, T.Activity_CD, T.Activity_DtTm 
FROM Employee E INNER JOIN Timecard T ON (E.Str_ID = T.Str_ID AND E.Emp_ID = T.Emp_ID)
WHERE (T.BUS_DT = @FromDate )
AND ((E.Str_ID = @Str_ID) OR (@Str_ID IS NULL OR @Str_ID = ''))
AND ((E.Emp_ID = @Emp_ID) OR (@Emp_ID IS NULL OR @Emp_ID = ''))
ORDER BY E.Str_ID ASC, E.Emp_ID ASC, T.Bus_DT_Seq ASC")
```

How data is bound: in the gridview I bound the Store_ID, Emp_ID and Employee name columns for Clock In and Clock out columns I manually separate and bind the data with the following code:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        EmpIDIndex = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Emp_ID"))
        ActivityNum = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Activity_CD"))

        If ActivityNum = 1 Then
            clockIn = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Activity_DtTm")
            e.Row.Cells(3).Text = clockIn
        ElseIf ActivityNum = 2 Then
            clockOut = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Activity_DtTm")
            e.Row.Cells(4).Text = clockOut
        End If

    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated

    Dim newRow As Boolean = False

    If (EmpIDIndex.Length > 0) AndAlso (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Emp_ID") IsNot Nothing) Then
        If EmpIDIndex = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Emp_ID")) Then
            newRow = False
        Else
            newRow = True
        End If
    End If

    If (EmpIDIndex.Length > 0) AndAlso (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Emp_ID") Is Nothing) Then
        newRow = True
        rowIndex = 0
    End If

    If newRow = True Then
        Dim GridView1 As GridView = DirectCast(sender, GridView)
        Dim NewTotalRow As New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert)
        NewTotalRow.Font.Bold = True
        Dim HeaderCell As New TableCell()
        HeaderCell.Text = "Next"
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2

        NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell)
        HeaderCell = New TableCell()
        HeaderCell.Text = " "
        NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell)
        GridView1.Controls(0).Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex + rowIndex, NewTotalRow)
        rowIndex += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried to use a new query but the result is the and it gives a null error due to the empty values manually bind it due to the null values

```
SELECT E.Str_ID, E.Emp_ID, (E.Last_Nm + ' ' + E.Frst_Nm) AS Name,
   T.Bus_DT, T.Activity_DtTm, T.Activity_CD, 
   (CASE WHEN  T.Activity_CD = '1' THEN T.Activity_DtTm END) as  Clock_In,
   (CASE WHEN  T.Activity_CD = '2' THEN T.Activity_DtTm END) as  Clock_OUT
FROM Employee E INNER JOIN Timecard T
ON E.Str_ID = T.Str_ID AND E.Emp_ID = T.Emp_ID
WHERE T.BUS_DT = '3/01/2007'
ORDER BY E.Str_ID ASC, E.Emp_ID ASC, T.Bus_DT_Seq
```

**Result**

The same problem occurs when Activity_DtTm and Activity are removed from selected.

[image]

**TimeCard Table Desing**

[image]

**Employee Table Desing**

[image]

I'm aware that you modify the output of the gridview manually i do not know how to modify it as the required output.

The other solution is to modify the query but i been having a lot of trouble with the query.

**QUESTION?**

How can i solve this problem with a query or a gridview manual output?

Comment: Seems very familiar this question.  I think the problem is nothing to do with your grid view , really to do with your query.  Take T.Bus_DT, T.Activity_CD, T.Activity_DtTm out of your query it will flatten it for a single employee

Comment: @Hursey the problem is that i need T.Bus_DT for searching, T.Activity_CD to separate the clock in/out dates and T.Activity_DtTm  are the clock in/outs which are also needed to perform equations. 

Is it possible to have both Clock In and Clock Out values displayed on the same row index by a query or a function?

Comment: Can you update your question with the table structures and complete sample data.

Comment: Why would you want Bob's check in and check out on separate lines? It seems that eventually you will want to find the time Bob spent at each store.

Comment: Wouldn't the store id and the Employee id both be required fields in the timecard table? Check your database. Did you design the database? The structure of these tables looks strange. Why would there be a store Id field in the employees table? Please show we the structure of both tables as requested by @Hursey

Comment: @Mary The Store_ID in the employee table is to identify which store the employee belongs to. The database and query was already design long before i started to work on the report. I have to use or modify that query for the report.

Comment: I think I see the problem. When an employee clocks out, the clock in record should be updated with the the clock out value in the TimeCard table. Currently, it looks like a new record is being added which makes things way more complicated and error prone.